# Como transformar código fonte em resumo digital hash?

Tags: hash, documentação, software

Para registro de um software, é solicitado:

- Realizar a transformação da documentação técnica (código-fonte) em resumo digital hash;

a documentação do INPI ainda informa: [...]O resumo hash é um texto de comprimento fixo contendo letras e números, que deve ser copiado e colado no campo correspondente do formulário eletrônico[...]

Como gero isso?

Comment: Conseguiu realizar o procedimento?

Comment: SIm David. Basta passar a pasta do projeto, pode ser a pasta compactada em um winrar, por um algoritmo HASH (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash). Qualquer um. O algoritmo utilizado precisa ser informado posteriormente.

Comment: A forma como você realizará isso, pode ser tanto desenvolvendo um script que faça isso para você como alguns sites que fazem pra você, e geram o HASH resultante.

Comment: Beleza.. daqui uns dias vou precisar fazer.. aproveito e posto uma resposta aqui.. Obrigado

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tive as mesmas dúvidas que você ao fazer o registro de um dos sistemas aqui da empresa. Vou compartilhar aqui a forma que encontrei para criar o resumo digital hash.

1) Eu acessei nosso repositório de códigos e baixei uma cópia do repositório, `projeto.zip`

2) Acessei o terminal do Mac, fui até o local onde estava o arquivo compactado e rodei o seguinte comando: `shasum -a 512 projeto.zip`

3) Copiei a chave gerada e informei no site do INPI.

OBS: O comando `shasum -a 512` me gerou uma criptografia **SHA-512**, mas você pode optar por outras criptografias, basta dar uma olhada no help do comando.

Comment: O que acontece quando vc tiver que resolver um bug ou uma pequena atualizacao de melhoria? vc deve gerar um novo hash e fazer outro registro?